# Activity Stack Android

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

I would like to understand very clearly how the activity stack works and how to use intent flags (SINGLE_TOP, etc etc) in a correct way. 
For example, If I want to avoid to instantiate any new activity if it is already instantiated, how could I do?

Thanks a lot in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [good official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for it.

If you really need **bad** solution like backstacking until you have needed activity from backstack you **can** do it using method `getRunningTasks` in `ActivityManager`, get position of activity you are searching for and backstack to it multiple times.